# Can we create Amazon Federated Identity Pools using API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, federated-identity

Can we create Amazon Federated Identity Pools using API?

I would like to automate these tasks.

Comment: You can do everything in AWS via API calls. See: [SDKs](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/#SDKs)

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  The SDK has everything you need.  A python SDK here: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/cognito-identity.html

Android here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android

Also here who you get and identity: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-credentials.html